# Select from 2 tables and order by 1

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables.

First:

```
TABLE Articles
  ID
```

Second:

```
TABLE Viewcount
  DATE        DATE  PK
  ARTICLE_ID  INT   PK  (MATCHES ID IN TABLE Articles)
  NUMVIEWS    INT
```

How do I select all IDs from table Articles and then order by NUMVIEWS (DESC) of Viewcount according to dates? 
I then need to append the IDs from Articles that were not found in viewcount to the End of the results in no particular order. 
I know it has to be some sort of Join but I can't figure it out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT id from Articles a
LEFT JOIN Viewcount v
ON  a.id = v.article_id
AND v.date = 'some date here'
ORDER BY v.numviews ,v.date desc
```

Comment: here to get ids from `articles` table

Comment: when I specify (WHERE v.date = 'some date here') it removes the rest of the IDs of Articles from the results that weren't found. Is there a way to specify a date range and then LEFT JOIN the remaining IDs from Articles that weren't found in the range?

Comment: edited my answer . then try to get the specifik date in the join ,not in where clause

Answer (score 1):

A simple join will suffice, yes:

```
SELECT a.id FROm Articles a LEFT JOIN Viewcount v
ON v.article_id = a.id
ORDER BY v.numviews desc, v.date
```

Comment: I need to return all IDs and order by NUMVIEWS/DATE, this only returns IDs that exist in both tables. I need to return IDs that exist in Articles but not in Viewcount as well..

Comment: You need to include that in the question then. Do note that you cannot sort rows in Articles by columns in Viewcount unless there is a real association between the tables. So the question for you is - For Articles with no viewcount, are they excluded from the resultset, included at the top of the resultset, or included at the bottom of the resultset?

Comment: Included at the bottom of the results in no particular order

Comment: Then use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: This almost works perfectly except I can't seem to limit the results from Viewcount according to date.. For example, if I need to get NUMVIEWS desc from Viewcount only for Today, ordering by v.date isn't doing it.. and if I specify WHERE v.DATE = 'some date range', it limits results from Articles again.

Comment: Also add `OR v.DATE IS NULL` to your WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM `Articles` `a`, `Viewcount` `v`
WHERE `v`.`ARTICLE_ID`=`a`.`ID`
ORDER BY `v`.`NUMVIEWS` DESC
```

Replace `SELECT *` by `` SELECT `a`.`ID` `` to get only the Article IDs.

Comment: I think he should select just ids

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID from (Articles JOIN Viewcount on Articles.ID = Viewcount.ID) ORDER BY Viewcount.NUMVIEWS, Viewcount.date
```